# Syncing a local file with two different git repository

Tags: git

I am working on a local project and I want to sync that project with two different git repos. I added the project, committed and pushed on one repo. but when i am pushing in second repo, It is giving a fatal error : The current branch master has no upstream branch

Comment: How are you pushing to the second repo? Have you set up the second repository, and added it as a remote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the branch name explicitly:

```
git push mySecondRepo master
```

Comment: Actually, `-u` sets mySecondRepo/master as the upstream of the current branch. https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html

Comment: that's because `git push mySecondeRepo master` is shorthand for `git push mySecondRepo master:master` which says push the local branch called `master` to a remote branch named `master` you could rename the  branch on the second upstream with `git push mySecondRepo master:secondMaster` and it would still create the remote branch. The point is that the `-u` is not necessary unless you want to set up that remote branch to be tracked.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm updating my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly specify both the *remote* you're pushing to, and the *branch* you're pushing to on that remote:

```
git push secondrepo master
```

Where "secondrepo" is the name you've given to `git remote add` with the URL of the second repository.

Each git branch allows you to specify an "upstream", which configures some default behavior for git commands -- `git pull` with no arguments will fetch and merge in its upstream, `git push` without arguments will automatically push to its upstream. You can configure an upstream in a few ways: using `git push -u secondrepo master` (short for `git push --set-upstream secondrepo master`), `git branch --set-upstream secondrepo/master`, or just editing `.git/config` by hand. git is complaining here because you've tried to use the shorthand, argumentless `git push`, but the current branch has no upstream to tell it what branch to update.

In your case, since you have *two* upstreams that you want to update, you'll likely want to use the full `git push <remote> <branch>` syntax each time.